# How to detect that haptic feedback is disabled on iOs device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, vibration

I want to to show message in my application when haptic feedback is disabled in phone settings. How to detect that haptic feedback is disabled in device settings?

Answer (score 1):

It's kludgy, but might this work?

```
- (BOOL)isHapticFeedbackDisabled {
  BOOL result = NO;
  UISelectionFeedbackGenerator *feedbackGenerator = [[UISelectionFeedbackGenerator alloc] init];
  [feedbackGenerator prepare];
  if ([feedbackGenerator.description containsString:@"prepared=0"]) result = YES;
  feedbackGenerator = nil;
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **no way** to check Haptic Feedback is enabled/disabled but there is private int `_feedbackSupportLevel` in UIKit for checking if device supports it:

```
func logFeedbackSupported() {
    let supportLevel = UIDevice.current.value(forKey: "_feedbackSupportLevel")
    print(supportLevel ?? "")
}
```

***0***: Not available,
**1**: First generation available (< iPhone 7),
**2**: Second generation available.

I advise you not to use Apples private APIs because:

1. The **API could be changed** in any version without you knowing about it.
2. Apple is parsing your app code to find out if you're using private API so be aware. Your app could be **rejected**.

Comment: When I disabled it in the settings, this method always return **2** on iPhone 7

Comment: @Yogan thanks for the test! So there's no way to check it I guess. Updated answer.